# How can I convert an uLong(64 bits) to byte array in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, long-integer

I need to write something to BLE device, only byte array can be accepted. But I want to write an unsigned long type integer, how can I convert it to byte array? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var source: ULong = 0uL            
val bytes = ByteArray(5)
bytes[0x0] = (source shr 32).toByte()
bytes[0x1] = (source shr 24).toByte()
bytes[0x2] = (source shr 16).toByte()
bytes[0x3] = (source shr 8).toByte()
bytes[0x4] = source.toByte()
```

depending if you want the bytes filled higher order at index 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun ULong.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val result = ByteArray(ULong.SIZE_BYTES)
    (0 until ULong.SIZE_BYTES).forEach {
        result[it] = this.shr(Byte.SIZE_BITS * it).toByte()
    }
    return result
}
```

And then use:
`someULongValue.toByteArray()`